# Why do function and method behave differently when used in an assert statement in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

When the return value of a method is used in an assert statement I get a verifier message "assertion might not hold." I understand that it is so because it doesn't hold all the time. However, to my surprise when it is a function, the assert statement is successfully verified. To clarify the point, here is the code I used.

```
method absmethod(x:int) returns (y:int)
  ensures 0<=y
{
  if x<0 {y:=-x;} else {y:=x;}
}

function absfunction(x:int):(y:int)
  ensures 0<=y
{
  if x<0 then -x else x
}
method {:main} T() {
  var v1:=absmethod(3);
  var v2:=absfunction(3);
  assert v2==3;  // assertion always holds
  assert v1==3; // verifier error: assertion might not hold
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for that is that methods are opaque, while functions are transparent for the verifier.
Methods often change the heap, so for the verifier, only its ensures and requires are relevant. That's also why, in Dafny, you cannot nest method calls, otherwise it becomes quickly very hard to reason about side-effects.
Functions, on the other side, are equivalent to the notion of mathematical functions, meaning they are pure. At most, they can read the heap. But for the verifier, a function call is equivalent to its definition - up to some unrolling degree if recursive.

With this in mind, you can actually use your function as a specification as well for the method, which is very common:

```
method absmethod(x:int) returns (y:int)
  ensures 0<=y
  ensures y == absfunction(x) // Here is the specification of the method, that's everything the verifier knows after this method call
{
  if x < 0 {y:=-x;} else {y:=x;}
}
```

If you do this, then your code verifies.
Even better, if you are often in this situation, where you want to have a functional pure specification but implement it with imperative code, you can use functions by methods, like this:

```
function absfunction(x:int):(y:int)
  ensures 0<=y
{
  if x < 0 then -x else x
} by method {
  if x < 0 {
    y := -x;
  } else {
    y := x;
  }
}
```

or even, for fun:

```
function absfunction(x:int):(y:int)
  ensures 0<=y
{
  if x < 0 then -x else x
} by method {
  y := 0;
  var i := x;
  while i != 0
    invariant x > 0 ==> i >= 0
    invariant x < 0 ==> i <= 0
    invariant if x > 0 then y + i == x else i - y == x
  {
    y := y + 1;
    if i > 0 {
      i := i - 1;
    } else {
      i := i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```